# My app stops working when I press Contact Us in the Nav bar

Tags: java, android

`ContactUsFragment.java`
I have gone through various posts but coudn't find any relevent answer. I am trying to add a location and few images in a fragment but the app is crashing. Error is in this file. The XML file is fine.

```
    public class ContactUsFragment extends FragmentActivity implements  OnMapReadyCallback {
    private GoogleMap mMap;

    public static ContactUsFragment newInstance(){
        ContactUsFragment fragment = new ContactUsFragment();
        return fragment;
    }

    public ContactUsFragment() {
    }

    @BindView(R.id.contact_us_root)
    LinearLayout root;


    public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_contact_us, container, false);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, rootView);
        TextView textView1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.t1);
        TextView textView2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.t2);
        TextView textView3 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.t3);
        TextView textView4 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.t4);
        TextView textView5 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.t5);
        TextView textView6 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.t6);

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ib1);
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.fb1);
        ImageView imageView1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ib2);
        imageView1.setImageResource(R.drawable.gp1);
        ImageView imageView2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ib3);
        imageView2.setImageResource(R.drawable.pin1);
        ImageView imageView3 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ib4);
        imageView3.setImageResource(R.drawable.add);
        ImageView imageView4 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ib5);
        imageView4.setImageResource(R.drawable.phone);
        ImageView imageView5 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ib6);
        imageView5.setImageResource(R.drawable.gmail);



        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        return rootView;
    }



    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        LatLng loc = new LatLng(12.77, 77.52);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(loc).title("Student Zone"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(loc));
    }}
01-18 14:12:04.827 30314-30314/in.astudentzone.studentzone E/UncaughtException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to write to field 'android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl android.support.v4.app.Fragment.mFragmentManager' on a null object reference
                                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.doAddOp(BackStackRecord.java:418)
                                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.replace(BackStackRecord.java:457)
                                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.replace(BackStackRecord.java:449)
                                                                                    at in.astudentzone.studentzone.activities.Home.selectDrawerItem(Home.java:133)
                                                                                    at in.astudentzone.studentzone.activities.Home$1.onNavigationItemSelected(Home.java:66)
                                                                                    at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView$1.onMenuItemSelected(NavigationView.java:152)
                                                                                    at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:810)
                                                                                    at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:152)
                                                                                    at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:957)
                                                                                    at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter$1.onClick(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:318)
                                                                                    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4789)
                                                                                    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19881)
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292)
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:699)
01-18 14:12:04.831 30314-30380/in.astudentzone.studentzone D/FA: Logging event (FE): _ae, Bundle[{_o=crash, _sc=Home, _si=3096521095531764912, timestamp=1484728924827, fatal=1}]
01-18 14:12:05.090 30314-30314/in.astudentzone.studentzone E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                             Process: in.astudentzone.studentzone, PID: 30314
                                                                             java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to write to field 'android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl android.support.v4.app.Fragment.mFragmentManager' on a null object reference
                                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.doAddOp(BackStackRecord.java:418)
                                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.replace(BackStackRecord.java:457)
                                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.replace(BackStackRecord.java:449)
                                                                                 at in.astudentzone.studentzone.activities.Home.selectDrawerItem(Home.java:133)
                                                                                 at in.astudentzone.studentzone.activities.Home$1.onNavigationItemSelected(Home.java:66)
                                                                                 at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView$1.onMenuItemSelected(NavigationView.java:152)
                                                                                 at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:810)
                                                                                 at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:152)
                                                                                 at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:957)
                                                                                 at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter$1.onClick(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:318)
                                                                                 at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4789)
                                                                                 at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19881)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:699)
01-18 14:12:06.574 30314-30314/in.astudentzone.studentzone I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 30314 SIG: 9
```

Comment: post your log cat

Comment: How should I share the logcat? @Reena

Comment: Seems ur ButterKnife is not responding use instead `.........(TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.t1);` for all using `rootView`

Comment: Didn't work :( @W4R10CK

Comment: Copy Text from 'Android Monitor'

Comment: what is the error u gettinf from Logcat.`AndroidMonitor > Logcat`